# Why do identical dataframes become different when changing rownames to the same?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

I've come across a strange behavior when playing with some dataframes: when I create two identical dataframes `a,b`, then swap their rownames around, they don't come out as identical:

```
rm(list=ls())

a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,3,4))
b <- a
identical(a,b)
#TRUE

identical(rownames(a),rownames(b))
#TRUE

rownames(b) <- rownames(a)

identical(a,b)
#FALSE
```

Can anyone reproduce/explain why?

Comment: Looks like the row names are initially numeric, but `rownames()` returns a character vector, so the row names end up as attributes of different types.

Comment: You can check the structure i.e. `c(NA, -3L)` is the first case changed to `c("1", "2", "3")`

Comment: Don't use `identical` for comparing dataframes. Use `all.equal(a,b)` which tells you the names are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is admittedly a bit confusing. Starting with `?data.frame` we see that:

> If row.names was supplied as NULL or no suitable component was found
>   the row names are the integer sequence starting at one (and such row
>   names are considered to be ‘automatic’, and not preserved by
>   as.matrix).

So initially `a` and `b` each have an attribute called `row.names` that are integers:

```
> str(attributes(a))
List of 3
 $ names    : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
 $ row.names: int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ class    : chr "data.frame"
```

But `rownames()` returns a character vector (as does `dimnames()`, actually a list of character vectors, called under the hood). So after reassigning the row names you end up with:

```
> str(attributes(b))
List of 3
 $ names    : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
 $ row.names: chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
 $ class    : chr "data.frame"
```